# php session lost after redirect - tried all things from google and stackoverflow

Tags: php, session-variables, session-cookies

I have a process_form page like this :

```
<?php
    include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
    include_once 'includes/functions.php';
    sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.
    if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.  
        if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
            // Login success
            header('Location: test.php');
            die();
        } else {
            // Login failed 
            header('Location: login.php?error=1');
            exit;
       }
   } else {
         // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
         echo 'Invalid Request';
  }

 ?>
```

If i do a `print_r($_SESSION)` after `//Login success` i have all `$_SESSION` OK. After redirect it's gone. I have tried almost all (put `exit;` `exit();` `die();` after `header()` and still nothing .

My test php page :

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
sec_session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

and the sec_session_start() function  :

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = true;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id(true);    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}
```

I set $_SESSION parameters in `login` function

I dont know what to do to debug this .

php.ini SESSION parameters :

```
session.save_path="C:\xampp\tmp"
session.use_strict_mode=0
session.use_cookies=1
session.use_only_cookies=1
session.name=PHPSESSID
session.cookie_lifetime=0
session.cookie_path=/
session.cache_expire=180
session.save_handler=files
```

After removing line by line from the `sec_session_start()` I made it work by removing this :

```
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        **$secure**,
        $httponly);
```

Now i can receive `$_SESSION` variable in test.php .

Update #2 : just setting `$secure = false` is working .

Comment: show you apache error log?

Comment: try to add " ob_start(); " on top of the page

Comment: @RanjeetSingh why?

Comment: @Naumov nothing in apache error log just undefined index username from a `echo $_SESSION['username']`

Comment: Loglevel set as E_ALL ?

Comment: @Naumov `error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`

Comment: try `var_dump(include('includes/functions.php'));` and check file on BOM-symbols and resave

Comment: @Naumov var_dump -> `int(1)` .. also check my updated post about headers

Comment: try to remove this line: `session_regenerate_id(true);`

Comment: i did that still the same

Comment: can you now try to put `false` instead of `true`?, because putting `true` removes the latest session id : [#php_link](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php)

Answer (score 1):

I know this code from [here @ WiKiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL).

Just comment out this line:

```
session_name($session_name);
```

and it will work. I'm not pro, so I'm not sure this is the best way to solve the problem but, you can get more info [here @ GitHub](https://github.com/peredurabefrog/phpSecureLogin/issues/29).

"Acording to this marc.info/?l=php-doc-bugs&m=120303453328364&w=2
you cannot set session name via session_name($session_name) if it's set using `php_admin_value` in 'httpd.conf' (it's feature not bug). It happens on shared hosting accounts."

Answer (score 0):

Problem is this

```
session_regenerate_id(true);    // regenerated the session, delete the old one.
```

Remove this line it always generating new id and removes old one.

Comment: How you are validating login and where you are implemented that login; may you share that code too?

Comment: after i check user and pass with database i set `$_SESSION['username'] = $db_user` and `return true;`

Comment: If this is sent `PHPSESSID=fdoadts7gu9qp28hk513j02sv6` to browser means session is already started somewhere; don't know may be in `functions.php` or `db_connect.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

`//session_regenerate_id(true);    // regenerated the session, delete the old one.`

As in the comment written, this line will delete the old session and regenerate a new one.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Answer (score 0):

You won't need this line:

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

This line will regenerate new ID which will overwrite the existing one.

> session_regenerate_id() will replace the current session id with a new one, and keep the current session information.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Comment: i just removed that line again and still same problem

Answer (score 0):

Actually i figure it out . I was the `$secure = true` options that forced sessions only over secure connections .